# How to build and count relationship in an optimized way in laravel?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm counting the hits like:

```
$country_id = Country::where('key', strip_tags($key))->pluck('id')->first();

$count = Hit::where( 'type', 'cities' )
                    ->where('country_id', $country_id)
                    ->distinct('type_id')
                    ->count();
```

But, It looks too slow. How do I make the relationship and improve the performance? It looks like the relationship should be like *a country can have many hits*?

Comment: Use raw sql with sum to obtain best performance

Comment: That query could be optimized in tiny ways, but it would be unlikely to change to be perceptively faster (unless this is inside a loop with 100s of repetitions?). When you say it "looks too slow" where are you seeing that? In a page display / output? Or do you have some timing around this block? I would look for other things, like whether `country_id` and `type` are indexed in the database. Side note: `->value('id')` will do the same thing as `->pluck('id')->first()`.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to keep relations then,define the relationship [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in the `Country` model.

```
class Country extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function hits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Hit::class, 'country_id');
    }
}
```

The rest you do as you do but add the relation in `$country`:

```
// Retrieve the country 
$country = Country::where('key', strip_tags($key))->first();

// Count the distinct type IDs
$count = $country->hits()
    ->where('type', 'cities')
    ->distinct('type_id')
    ->count();
```